# RegEx. Check and pad string to ensure certain string format is used

Tags: regex, string, formatting

Is it possible to take a string, and reformat it to ensure the output is always the same format.

I have an identification number that always follows the same format:

e.g.

```
   166688205F02

   16         66882          05     F          02
 (15/16) (any 5 digit no) (05/06) (A-Z) (any 2 digit no)
```

Sometimes these are expressed as:

```
   66882 5F 2
   668825F2
   66882 5 F 2
```

I want to take any of these lazy expressions, and pad them to form to proper format as above (defaulting as 16 for the first group).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your numbers can be matched by the following regex:

```
^ *(1[56])? *(\d{5}) *(0?[56]) *([A-Z]) *(\d{1,2}) *$
```

Here is a rough breakdown. I named the parts of the identification number. You may have more appropriate names for them.:

```
^ *         #Start the match at the beginning of a string and consume all leading spaces if any.
(1[56])?    #GROUP 1: The Id number prefix. (Optional)
 *          #Consume spaces if any.
(\d{5})     #GROUP 2: The five digit identifier code.
 *          #Consume spaces if any.
(0?[56])    #GROUP 3: The two digit indicator code.
 *          #Consume spaces if any.
([A-Z])     #GROUP 4: The letter code.
 *          #Consume spaces if any.
(\d{1,2})   #GROUP 5: The end code.
 *$         #End the match with remaining spaces and the end of the string.
```

You didn't mention the language you are using. Here is a function I wrote in C# that uses this regex to reformat an input identification number.

```
private string FormatIdentificationNumber(string inputIdNumber) {
    const string DEFAULT_PREFIX = "16";
    const string REGEX_ID_NUMBER = @"^ *(1[56])? *(\d{5}) *(0?[56]) *([A-Z]) *(\d{1,2}) *$";
    const int REGEX_GRP_PREFIX = 1;
    const int REGEX_GRP_IDENTIFIER = 2;
    const int REGEX_GRP_INDICATOR = 3;
    const int REGEX_GRP_LETTER_CODE = 4;
    const int REGEX_GRP_END_CODE = 5;

    Match m = Regex.Match(inputIdNumber, REGEX_ID_NUMBER, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (!m.Success) return inputIdNumber;

    string prefix = m.Groups[REGEX_GRP_PREFIX].Value.Length == 0 ? DEFAULT_PREFIX : m.Groups[REGEX_GRP_PREFIX].Value;
    string identifier = m.Groups[REGEX_GRP_IDENTIFIER].Value;
    string indicator = m.Groups[REGEX_GRP_INDICATOR].Value.PadLeft(2, '0');
    string letterCode = m.Groups[REGEX_GRP_LETTER_CODE].Value.ToUpper();
    string endCode = m.Groups[REGEX_GRP_END_CODE].Value.PadLeft(2, '0');
    return String.Concat(prefix, identifier, indicator, letterCode, endCode);
}
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you. I'm trying to learn this (not just copy and paste), so you're explanation is v helpful. And it is C# i'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace space character with a blank one.

In JS for example :

```
"66882 5F 2".replace(' ','') // Will output "668825F2"
"66882 5 F        2".replace(' ','') // Will output "668825F2"
```

With regex, you can use "\s" delimiter for white spaces

First you eliminate spaces by replacing blank characters, then you use this regex

```
^1[5|6]([0-9]{5})0[5|6][A-Z]([0-9]{2})$
```

Comment: I may be doing it wrong, but i tried a replace using this regex expression and it did nothing (I got the same string I passed in).

Comment: The regex only check if the final identifier is correct, you have to "str_replace" all space characteres before verify the regex